# Get key when object is found in value's array

Tags: ruby

Let's say I have a hash like this:

```
h = {100 => ["a","b"], 200 => ["c","d"]}
```

What is the fastest / most concise way to get the corresponding key back (like 100 or 200) when I know one of the array values (like a or d)? Can I use something like `find` or `select` or `map`?

Would it be easier if my hash was like this?

```
h = {["a","b"] => 100, ["c","d"] => 200}
```

Comment: Hashes use `{}`, not `[]`.

Comment: Wow, that's embarrassing. Sorry, I fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hashes use `{}` instead of `[]`. But you could accomplish it like this:

```
h = {100 => ["a","b"], 200 => ["c","d"]}

desired_value = "a" # the value you want to search for

h.select { |k,v| v.include? desired_value }.keys
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a reason to use `select` instead of `find`?

Comment: Depends on your scenario, `select` returns an array of matched values and `find` only returns the first occurrence. If your arrays have unique values or you only care for the first occurrence, you can use `find`.